# apt update gives error on brave browser

Tags: apt

When i run apt update it gives:

`Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'`

I use Kubuntu 22.04.1 64 bit, so how do i solve this?

Comment: Please add output of the file containing "brave" in the name form `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ending with `.list`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error message is indicating that the repository "https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease" does not support the i386 architecture, and as a result, the "main/binary-i386/Packages" file is being skipped during the update process. This error message can be safely ignored or you can try one of the following fixes:

You can add `arch=amd64` to your `brave-browser-release.list` file. [The instructions provided by Brave Browser](https://brave.com/linux/#debian-ubuntu-mint) for installing on Ubuntu try to accommodate every architecture. That's why the instructions omit `arch=amd64` when they suggest adding a `.list` file for brave. The upside for Brave is that identical instructions will work on AMD64 and ARM machines. But this isn't ideal for AMD64 users because it leads to the problem you're seeing. Since you have an AMD64 machine, you can run this modified instruction to fix the problem:

```bash
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
```

This command creates or replaces the `brave-browser-release.list` file so that it includes the `arch=amd64` parameter.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you can also try removing the line containing `i386` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

After applying the fix, run the following command again:

```
sudo apt update
```