Upgrade Error from 22.04 to 24.04
I am trying to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. I am having this problem:
It says:

Error during update
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

But I don't have any problems with my internet. And I tried both Ethernet and Wi-Fi, and neither works.
I click on "Upgrade Now" button, then it successfully downloads stuff for a while, and then it gets stuck and throws this error.
Then I see this for a moment:

And then it all closes.
Other problems also exist. But I found the solution nowhere.
One thing to note here: package upgrades are working from terminal, but GUI upgrading is buggy for some days.
This is what I get after running sudo apt upgrade:

The following packages have been kept back:
python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

The above message is to provide context only, and it's not the question. It might still be relevant.
How do I solve this problem and upgrade to 24.04 LTS?

You are asking 2 questions. This site allows only 1 question per post. Please  edit the question and make a separate question for the second issue.

@DavidDE I am adding that just as a context, that's not my question. My only question is about upgrading. I know how to force upgrade held back packages. I just shared the held back message because it has packages with the word "update" in them, so I thought that those might be relevant.

I have the same problem with the upgrade from 22 to 24 LTS despite good network connection. Hope somebody from Ubuntu will take it seriously and provide a solution.

I'm having this same exact issue and searching for an answer - this thread may be worthwhile - https://community.frame.work/t/error-while-updating-to-ubuntu-24/57143/6

I have solved the problem, and I am now currently using 24.04 LTS.
I don't know exactly what worked.

Here are the things that I did:

There was a GPG key issue with GitHub CLI following a recent update, and I solved it following https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/9569.

There was an error message from Brave, saying it doesn't support i386 architecture, so I mentioned amd64 explicitly on brave-browser-release.list  following https://askubuntu.com/a/1453449/1030478, and followed installation instruction with the said modification.

Then I followed https://community.frame.work/t/error-while-updating-to-ubuntu-24/57143/6 and tried to upgrade via do-release-upgrade. I saw that my /boot partition was almost full and it needed additional space. I was ready to go with GParted, but, following https://askubuntu.com/a/90219/1030478, I deleted old Linux kernel files, and gained the required space.


After doing all these, by running do-release-upgrade, I was able to successfully upgrade.

It took ~40 minutes.
And on running neofetch, I can see:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64

For me, this issue is solved, and I am using it right now.
So, I had some problems with updates, and also low space on /boot. After mitigating both, I was able to upgrade to 24.04 LTS using the command line command do-release-upgrade. I was not able to trigger the GUI upgrade window, and did not want to.

FWIW I had the same error as the OP, attempted a CLI upgrade with do-release-upgrade, saw that there was a problem with gh (a github app which I'd installed before September 2024) and then followed the instructions in point 1 above and now things are working fine.

I had exactly the same problem and the solution in point 1, i.e. using script from https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/9569, worked for me.

I am having the same issue.
I have already tried some ways like changing from Download From to Main Server, Server For India not working.
I also have tried with the terminal and found one error:
err https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable inrelease %0d%0a the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: no_pubkey
it seems issue related to brave browser for my case public key is expired or somehting, follow this link https://brave.com/linux/#release-channel-installation this form brave browser official document and try again.
This works for me, and now I am using 24.04
